# Ajax Call not happening for WebMethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a WebMethod using a function that contains Ajax Call request.But it is giving `Internal Server error 500`.Here is the function that contains the Ajax ..

```
function ajaxCall(URL) {

var serverData = "";

$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (queriedData, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        serverData = queriedData;
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
return serverData;
}
```

and Here i am trying to Call this jquery function ..

```
 var checkInBookingIDData = ajaxCall(URL);
```

and Here is the URL value that i am trying to pass..

```
Default.aspx/getCheckinData?BookingId=102
```

I am not able to find out where i am going wrong .Please help me ..Thanks..

Update:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string getCheckinData(string BookingID)
 {
   //My code goes her
 }
```

Comment: Apparently there's a problem with the server and it has nothing to do with your ajax request.

Comment: @dekkard Okay.I have updated my Web method also ..Please let me know where i am going wrong..?

Comment: Can you manually do the POST with ```BookingId=102``` param to your URL and see if it actually works? BTW that's a strange URL - ```Default.aspx/getCheckinData```. What is ```getCheckinData``` here?

Comment: @dekkard `getCheckinData` is a WebMethod ..Please see my updated post with Method name ..Yes i am able to call that URL manually

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (note how parameter is passed as `data: { BookingId: 102 }`):

```
function ajaxCall(URL) {

    // URL must be .../Default.aspx/getCheckinData

    var serverData = "";

    $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        data: { BookingId: 102 },
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type : 'POST',
        success : function (queriedData, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            serverData = queriedData;

            // process serverData here
        },
        error : function (request, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });

    // This won't work this way
    //return serverData;
}
```

Comment: Is you WebMethod available online? I could try to do a request myself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass your query string parameters directly by URL if you define your request type as POST as this will be a GET request [Refer](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp). In the POST request query string are send as HTTP message body. The format should be as follows:

```
function ajaxCall(URL) {
  var serverData = "";

  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ BookingId: '102' }),
    success: function (queriedData, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        serverData = queriedData;
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
       alert(error);
    }
 });
 return serverData;
}
```

Just make sure that your URL ends with the name of your method, '**Default.aspx/getCheckinData**'.

Comment: I tried your code but it is giving me `"Invalid web service call...eter:`